# ASP.NET Core 5 Web API for CRUD return value is too complicated for the controller to return

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

In my ASP.NET Core 5 Web API controller, I have this code:

```
[HttpGet("GetByUID/{uid:int}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<PTHeading>> GetPTHeading(int uid) 
{
    APIEntityResponse<PTHeading> getResponse = new();

    var getResult = await _controller.GetByValue("UID_PTHEADING", uid.ToString());

    if (getResult is null) 
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
            $"Error retrieving {m_sControllerName} data from the database.");
    } 
    else 
    {
        return Ok(getResult.Result);
    }
}
```

That yields the following result in SWAGGER:

```
{
  "value": {
    "isSuccess": true,
    "errorMessages": [],
    "data": {
      "uiD_PTHEADING": 14,
      "uiD_CUSTOMER": 17,
      "txT_PTHEADING_NAME": "Exterior",
      "booL_IS_ACTIVE": true,
      "inT_SORT_ORDER": 1
    }
  },
  "formatters": [],
  "contentTypes": [],
  "declaredType": null,
  "statusCode": 200
}
```

This is not what I need to be returned.  I need only this section to be returned...

```
{
  "isSuccess": true,
  "errorMessages": [],
  "data": {
     "uiD_PTHEADING": 14,
     "uiD_CUSTOMER": 17,
     "txT_PTHEADING_NAME": "Exterior",
     "booL_IS_ACTIVE": true,
     "inT_SORT_ORDER": 1
   }
}
```

The getResult.Result value is shown here:

[image]

I don't know how to get this as a return value.

Any comments, questions or solutions are welcome.  Thanks...John

Comment: What is your `getResult.Result` value? If the value of `getResult.Result` is the object in `value` as the JSON snippet and you are using ASP.NET Core API, have you try to replace `ActionResult` with `IActionResult`? Would be great if you can specify which .NET API framework you used: .NET Framework or .NET Core/.NET 5 or above?

Comment: Thank you Yong Shun...I added an image of the getResult.Result data in the question. I changed ActionResult to IActionResult and showed compilation-error.  I added information of .NET-5 version.  Thank you for your questions.  Additionally, I cannot reference the getResult.Result.Value  property from the new image in the question. That "Value" data is the data I am trying to get from the controller, back to SWAGGER and the client-code.  Thank you.

Comment: Based on what I see, I think straightway return the `getResult` should be fine. `return getResult as ActionResult<PTHeading>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your current code, the `return Ok(getResult.Result);` will treat the value of `getResult.Result` ([`OkObjectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okobjectresult?view=aspnetcore-7.0)) as the response body.

You can return the response body with `getResult.Result.Value`. Note that you should check the status code first and control the value/action result to be returned.

```cs
else 
{
    if (getResult.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCodes.Status200OK)
        return Ok(getResult.Result.Value);
    else
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
            $"Error retrieving {m_sControllerName} data from the database."); // Custom handling when status code is not 200
}
```

Or you can just return the `getResult` directly.

```cs
else 
{
    return getResult as ActionResult<PTHeading>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Yong Shun for the Answer and solution... the "return getResult as ActionResult<PTHeading>;" did the trick!!!! I now have the proper return-value.  Thank you very much.